# How to generate a new numeric column to represent a sequence of characters in R?

Tags: r, sequence

The data I have is like sdf:

```
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc","cc","cc","cc","aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb")
sdf = data.frame(s)
```

What I want to do is generate a column that goes from 1 to whatever, but for every repeated character the number doesn't change. I can get a sequence with the following:

```
sdf$wrongseq<-seq(1:nrow(sdf))
```

But how do I get the sequence like the description above:

```
rightseq<- c(1, 2, 3,3,3,3,4,5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7)
sdf = cbind(sdf,rightseq)
```

Comment: `c(1, cumsum(s[-1] != s[-length(s)])+1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
rleid(sdf$s)
#[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7
```

---

```
# if no package to be loaded:
x = rle(as.character(sdf$s))$lengths #rle calculates lengths of equal values
# x
# [1] 1 1 4 1 1 1 4
rep(seq_along(x), x)
#[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7
```